# Why would whitespace cause a fatal error in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax-error, whitespace, fatal-error

I have an associative array that, for all intents and purposes, *appears* to have absolutely no reason to throw even a warning. The entirety of the source code is as follows:

```
<?php
$entries = array(
  array('date' => '2012-08-12', 'change' => '-19'),
  array('date' => '2012-08-13', 'change' => '-21'),  
  array('date' => '2012-08-14', 'change' => '-19'),
  array('date' => '2012-08-15', 'change' => '-17'),
);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  print $entry['date'] . ': ' . $entry['change'] . '<br/>'; 
}
```

To me everything looks fine, however when I go to view the output in my browser, I get the following error message:

**Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting ')' in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wtf2.php** on line **5**

I looked a little closer and then discovered that on line 4, there was what appeared to be a trailing space or two (which I didn't even think twice about, at first). However when I copied the whitespace, pasted it into a new document like so (line 2):

```
<?php
$whitespace = '  ';
print rawurlencode($whitespace);
```

... and then viewed the output in my browser, this is what I saw:

```
%C2%A0%20
```

I *would* ask, "How did that get there in the first place?" but I don't really think that's a feasible question to answer. So my actual question is this: how does whitespace like that differ from any other whitespace (especially to the point where it causes a fatal error when ran through the PHP interpreter)? And is there a way to prevent this from happening in the future?

PS: I'm running PHP version 5.3.20 (via MAMP Pro on a Mac).

PPS: To clarify, **WHEN THE WHITESPACE ITSELF IS DELETED, THE CODE RUNS FINE.**

Comment: It's probably not recognized by the tokenizer — why would it be?

Comment: I've seen that type of issue show up when copying and pasting from documents. Often when copying from microsoft programs such as word you will get some of their special characters that like to screw up php and cause it to throw errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is a UTF-8 encoded non-breaking space (`%C2%A0`, aka `&nbsp;`), which breaks PHP's parser.  It's a known problem with PHP that is marked as "won't fix" because people "might use this character as part of an identifier."  See [Request #38766 Nonbreaking whitespace breaks parsing](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38766).

Comment: Incredible. After reading that request, i tried it and sure enough, you can in fact create a variable out of `$ ` alone. I had no idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

just banged my head for about an hour going totally insane about this.

Notepad++ doesn't show ANY difference between a regular space and a nbsp.

If you wonder how this character actually got into your code, this is how i got mine :
altgr + space

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Please have a read of [how to write a good answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider editing your answer to fit the guidelines better. :^)