# Undefined PHP function filter_input

Tags: php, mamp, php-extension

I am trying to use the predefined function in PHP `filter_input`

But I get the following: `Call to undefined function filter_input()...`

The line it fails on is:

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

I can confirm there is a `$_POST['email']` that has a value and that I am using PHP 5.5.12 and the filter extension was enabled by default in 5.2.0 .

I'm not sure what I am missing to access the function that should be already accessible.

```
    $error_msg = "";

    if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
        // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Not a valid email
            $error_msg .= 'The email address you entered is not valid';
    }

        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
```

There isn't much code. It doesn't make it too far yet...

Comment: Please show us the full script where you use this line in!

Comment: The line looks fine compared to the docs, so must be something elsewhere in your code. Please try to provide us with all relevant code.

Comment: Is the "filter" installed? `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and what server are you running under? Plus, did you restart after making any changes?

Comment: We need more code, because the $email line is just fine man!

Comment: `<?php
if(!function_exists("filter_var")) {
    echo "Filter extension not found. (PHP " . phpversion() .")";
}
else {
    echo "Filter extension loaded. All is well! :)/>";
}
?>`

Comment: I just ran your code above and it says Filter Extension not found. I am running my webserver off MAMP. So it's using Apache.

Comment: If you made any changes to any `.ini` files or other related server files and didn't restart all services including Apache, then those won't take effect. Did you make any changes in regards to that?

Comment: I made no changes to anything, since I assumed the functions would be there by default, but apparently not. Is it easy to enable it or add it?

Comment: See this http://www.commentics.org/support/knowledgebase.php?article=36 it's in your `php.ini` file. Make sure you restart all services after doing that.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php  says (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0) what is your version?

Comment: @KimAlexander Please read the question first before writing a useless comment!

Comment: @Rizier123 Sorry, my bad :-)

Comment: As *inadvisable* but quick workaround, there are userland implementations for the `filter` extension; such as http://fossies.org/linux/upgradephp/ext/unfinished/filter.php (doesn't include _VALIDATE_EMAIL, but FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function filter\_var()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11735538)

Comment: @Fred -ii- I changed the PHP.ini and no difference. Shouldn't if be pointing to a file? I checked my Apache httd.conf and I see a LoadModule line with mod_filter.so but not sure if it's the same thing.

Comment: That I couldn't say. I've never had to adventure myself (that far) in that area before. See if Mario can help you out.

Comment: That answer just says to have it installed, but it's pre-compilation configuration flag - not a php.ini one. Still don't know how to fix it :/

Comment: but what is php_info response? 
"Input Validation and Filtering" enabled???

Comment: @KimAlexander I did a find and can't see anything to resemble Input with Filter or Validation on the phpInfo. Something is missing from my php configuration, I'm sure the filter isn't the only one missing, just the first issue I ran into.

Comment: did you restart Apache service after changing php.ini?

Comment: Can you run this code and tell us what it says? `<?php print 'Filter extension ' . (extension_loaded('filter') ? 'exists.' : 'does not exist.'); ?>`

Comment: @KimAlexander Yes, I restarted everything.

Comment: Also, did you happen to copy/paste the text `filter_input`? If so, there's a chance that some whitespace was accidentally copied along with it, which in some cases breaks everything. I had this problem once and it drove me nuts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461759/why-would-whitespace-cause-a-fatal-error-in-php

Comment: @jerdiggity It doesn't exist, Fred -ii- posted something similar above.

Comment: I just uninstalled MAMP and reinstalled it, and now I see the Input with Filter or Validation part. Weird.